# Auto updating links between several sheets to a Summary Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, box

Several countries within our organization use the same template excel file to track capacity within their country. So one worksheet per country.

Because of COVID19, we now need to see capacity across the globe so we can pull help into countries that need it from one's that can give it.

We use box to store everyone's workbooks, so we can get live updates.

So what I've done is I've pulled in one row that contains all the information we need from each country's workbook and created something that looks like the below

[image: Summary sheet glimpse]

So far so good.

The problem I'm running into is on how to keep this updated in the future? The way I've linked the workbooks looks something like this

`='C:\Users\User1\Box\PIPELINE\[FRANCE PIPELINE 2020 - 01 04 20.xlsm]Pipeline'!CB6`

As you can see, this is referenced only to my computer, so it won't update unless I open the summary file every day and update the links and save.

Does anyone have a better idea than what I'm about to do:

- Write a code that updates links and saves the document
- Ask my buddy who has a virtual machine/server that's running 24/7 if I can just pop this file in there, download box sync to it, and have him keep the file open with this code running say... every hour?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Put your file `FRANCE PIPELINE 2020 - 01 04 20.xlsm` into the same folder as your summary file on every computer. Then the files can be in different folders eg `C:\Folder1\…` on one computer and `C:\Folder2\…` on another computer but you don't need to update the links on different computers as long as file name `FRANCE PIPELINE 2020 - 01 04 20.xlsm` does not change.

If the changeing filename is an issue (looks like there is a date in it) just rename it to something generic like `Current_FRANCE.xlsm` and link that to your summary file. If you get new data you just need to name it `Current_FRANCE.xlsm` and it is linked automatically.

So maybe writing a script that moves the new data files from your box into the summary files folder and name them `Current_FRANCE.xlsm` can be a solution.

Note that *"keep the file open with this code running"* might not work because as long as he has the file open all the others will not be able to access the file for writing. Files can be opened in write mode only once, all the others will have read-only access automatically.

So if you have a folder structure like

```
C:\Folder1\…
    … Summary.xlsm
    … Current_FRANCE.xlsm
    … Current_GERMANY.xlsm
    … Current_ITALY.xlsm
```

And you move the whole structure to eg `C:\Folder2\SomeCompletelyDifferentFolder\…` and open `Summary.xlsm` the links should still work.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for taking the time to respond! The issue I run into is that since this file is stored on box, another user who opens the file won't have the same paths I do. Box has a sync tool much like onedrive/sharedrive where (from what I understand) uploads the files onto the users computers so it can be accessed live, but it's really being held by their own servers. So for me box files are stores here: `C:\Users\User1\Box\ ` but for you it would be stored here: `C:\Users\Pᴇʜ\Box\ `, depending on the tool it could also be here: `C:\Users\Pᴇʜ\Box Sync\ `

Comment: So the folders I have are currently stored exactly like you've suggested, although I didn't think about the date field. I'll definitely have to change that!

Comment: @Pinlop are you sure that `Summary.xlsm` is in the exact same path as `Current_FRANCE.xlsm`? Then they should automatically work for every user. Open **all your files at the same time** and make sure to change the formulas from `='C:\Users\User1\Box\PIPELINE\[FRANCE PIPELINE 2020 - 01 04 20.xlsm]Pipeline'!CB6` to `='[Current_FRANCE.xlsm]Pipeline'!CB6` (without the path!) once. Then save and open in another box after sync and it works there too. I always do that and it works perfektly.